# I can't get my jquery ajax post to connect with my php page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

```
php
<?php

include 'connection.php';
echo "reached page";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO flagged ( ID,URL,COUNT,comment)VALUES ( :id,    :url, :count,:COMMENT )"); 
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindParam(':url', $url);
$stmt->bindParam(':count', $count);
$stmt->bindParam(':COMMENT', $comment);

$id = NULL;
$url = $_POST['url']);
$count = 1;
$comment = $_POST['data']);
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#flagForm').submit(function(){
return false;
});
$('#flag').click(function(){
    $('#comment').show();
});
$('body').on('click', '#commentSubmit', function(e) {
    $.post('flag.php',
    {
        data:$('#comment').val(),
        url:(window.location)
    },
    function(response){
        alert(response);
    });
});
});
```

html

```
<div id='comment'><h1 ></h1>
    <form id="flagForm" action="flag.php" method="post">
    <textarea id='commentData' placeholder='whats the problem' ></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id='commentSubmit' />
</form>
</div>
```

I can't seem to get my post to reach my php page. I have never had this problem before. The object is to flag a page by users. I have another post method and php page in using the same connection so that can't be it. Any help would be appreciated. And there is more to the jquery and html but this is all that is relative to the problem.

Comment: first thing to check is if the ajax call went through.  Did it return with a 500 error?  200 but no body?  Never called at all?  Use browser debugging tools available in most browsers to check that.  If a call was never placed, then it's not a php issue - it's purely a jquery/javascript issue.

Comment: thanks i did not know you could do that. I will check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#comment` is a div, you have to call `.val()` on the input/textarea with the data

```
data:$('#commentData').val(),
```

I see you get an illegal invocation error here `url:(window.location)` use `window.location.href` instead .

`window.location` is an object that jQuery cant serialize so you get that error.

Comment: thanks that and there were unnecessary ")" in the php. But the database still was not changed.

Answer (score 1):

You PHP code is a bit out of order. Instead of this:

```
include 'connection.php';
echo "reached page";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO flagged ( ID,URL,COUNT,comment)VALUES ( :id,    :url, :count,:COMMENT )"); 
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindParam(':url', $url);
$stmt->bindParam(':count', $count);
$stmt->bindParam(':COMMENT', $comment);

$id = NULL;
$url = $_POST['url']);
$count = 1;
$comment = $_POST['data']);
$stmt->execute();
```

You should be doing this:

```
include 'connection.php';

echo "reached page";

$id = NULL;
$url = $_POST['url']);
$count = 1;
$comment = $_POST['data']);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO flagged ( ID,URL,COUNT,comment)VALUES ( :id,    :url, :count,:COMMENT )"); 
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindParam(':url', $url);
$stmt->bindParam(':count', $count);
$stmt->bindParam(':COMMENT', $comment);

$stmt->execute();
```

Of course, you also should not be inserting user input directly into a database, either, but I assume this is not a real application at this point...

Comment: thanks no I am just trying to get it to work before I add checks and sanitize the data.

Comment: @user1204597 I'm just happy to see someone using preparing statements in PHP, to be honest... :)